# Display the number of rows inserted into a table from an existing table

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, insert, count

Please how can display the number of rows inserted into an archive table using Microsoft SQL server 2012 with Stored Procedure. I have my code display below. I ran the code successful, but calling the stored procedure, I got error message says

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5
>   Procedure p_moveTransHisttoArchive3a, Line 0 Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Here is my code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Production.p_moveTransHisttoArchive3a', N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE Production.p_moveTransHisttoArchive3a;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Production.p_moveTransHisttoArchive3a
    @FiveDaysAgo    DATETIME
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
        DECLARE @counter INT;
        SET @counter = @@ROWCOUNT
        INSERT INTO Production.TransactionHistoryArchive
            SELECT*
            FROM Production.TransactionHistory
            WHERE  TransactionDate <= @FiveDaysAgo
            RETURN @counter --No of rows moved
END;
GO
```

Comment: You need `SET @counter = @@ROWCOUNT` (or just `RETURN @@ROWCOUNT`) *after* the `INSERT`

Comment: The title is unrelated to the error you show ... presumably either `TransactionDate ` is not a `DATETIME`.

Comment: You need to be explicit with your statements. You should list all the columns by name in both the insert AND the select that is used to populate it.

Comment: And the way you have this coded it will ALWAYS return 1 because you check @@rowcount before you do the insert. Also, you are using rowcount as the return value. You should either change this to a select so it will be in the resultset OR create an OUTPUT parameter to hold the number of rows.

Comment: @Alex, I already SET '@Count' above the select statement

Comment: @Sean Lange, thanks. Please can you provide me with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something close to what you want I think. Why is your inbound parameter named FiveDaysAgo? If you want to always get rows that are older than five days ago that belongs INSIDE the proc, not as a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Production.p_moveTransHisttoArchive3a
    @FiveDaysAgo    DATETIME 
    , @RowCount int OUTPUT
AS
    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO Production.TransactionHistoryArchive
    (
        Col1
        , Col2
    )
    SELECT Col1
        , Col2
    FROM Production.TransactionHistory
    WHERE  TransactionDate <= @FiveDaysAgo

    select @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```